# Why is my test failing even though the data is in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm having trouble understanding why my test is failing. I have a component that renders some data from an API call, and I can see the data in the DOM when I inspect the page. However, my test is failing, and it seems like it doesn't expect the data to be in the DOM.

Here's my test code:

```
 it("Displays visitors on the virtual table", async () => {
      const render = mountApp();
      render();
      await loginToEmpl();
      const act = screen.getByText(/actions/i);
      expect(act).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
```

When I run this test, I get the following error:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /actions/i. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.` details about it: \`Ignored nodes: comments, \<script /\>, \<style /\>
\<body\>
\<div\>
\<header
class="MuiPaper-root MuiPaper-elevation MuiPaper-elevation4 MuiAppBar-root MuiAppBar-colorPrimary MuiAppBar-positionFixed makeStyles-bar-16 mui-fixed css-iqsc9j-MuiPaper-root-MuiAppBar-root"
\\\>
\<div
class="MuiToolbar-root MuiToolbar-gutters MuiToolbar-regular makeStyles-toolbar-17 css-1t29gy6-MuiToolbar-root"
\\\>
\<div
class="makeStyles-logo-20"
data-testid="logo"
\\\>
\<svg
height="30px"
viewBox="0 0 551 80"
width="207px"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
\\\>
\<g
fill="none"
fill-rule="evenodd"
stroke="none"
stroke-width="1"
\\\>
\<g
transform="translate(-364 -374)"
\\\>
\<g
transform="translate(364 374)"
\\\>
\<g
fill="#635BFF"
\\\>
\<path
d="M0 28.138h64.215a8.946 8.946 0 018.946 8.946v5.977a8.946 8.946 0 01-8.946 8.946H8.946A8.946 8.946 0 010 43.061V28.138z"
/\>
\<path
d="M9.689 0h78.254a8.946 8.946 0 018.946 8.946v.01a8.946 8.946 0 01-8.946 8.946H18.635a8.946 8.946 0 01-8.946-8.946V0z"
transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 106.578 0)"
/\>
\<path
d="M9.689 62.098h78.254a8.946 8.946 0 018.946 8.946v.01A8.946 8.946 0 0187.943 80H18.635a8.946 8.946 0 01-8.946-8.946v-8.956z"
transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 106.578 0)"
/\>
\</g\>
\<path
d="M149.55 61.988c4.493 0 9.735-.898 12.88-2.17 2.097-.824 2.996-2.171 2.996-4.117v-4.117c0-2.246-1.648-2.77-4.119-1.722-3.145 1.273-6.815 1.946-10.185 1.946-6.44 0-9.286-2.32-9.885-7.485l11.233-.749c9.511-.673 14.154-4.416 14.154-11.677 0-8.084-6.665-13.174-17.299-13.174-13.405 0-20.669 7.71-20.669 21.932 0 14.596 6.665 21.333 20.894 21.333zm-8.388-25.076c.3-5.913 3.07-9.132 7.938-9.132 3.745 0 5.991 1.572 5.991 4.267 0 2.77-2.246 3.967-7.114 4.341l-6.815.524zm41.703 24.253c2.172 0 2.995-.898 2.995-3.07V31.898c2.097-1.796 4.868-2.77 7.19-2.77 4.118 0 5.766 2.47 5.766 8.684v20.285c0 2.17.898 3.069 2.995 3.069h6.216c2.172 0 3.07-.898 3.07-3.07V36.764c0-1.647-.15-3.294-.374-4.791 2.696-1.871 5.317-2.845 7.563-2.845 4.044 0 5.692 2.47 5.692 8.684v20.285c0 2.17.973 3.069 3.07 3.069h6.216c2.171 0 2.995-.898 2.995-3.07V36.314c0-11.826-4.643-17.59-14.303-17.59-5.092 0-9.885 1.721-13.93 5.09-2.32-3.369-5.84-5.09-11.082-5.09-4.643 0-9.361 1.721-12.431 4.416v-.599c0-2.096-.824-2.919-3.07-2.919h-4.794c-2.096 0-2.995.898-2.995 2.994v35.48c0 2.172.899 3.07 2.995 3.07h6.216zm71.507 13.024c2.172 0 2.996-.898 2.996-3.069V60.491c2.172.824 4.942 1.497 7.788 1.497 12.356 0 19.171-8.084 19.171-22.606 0-13.099-6.066-20.66-16.7-20.66-4.942 0-9.286 1.947-11.607 4.492v-.599c0-2.096-.899-2.994-3.07-2.994h-4.793c-2.097 0-2.996.898-2.996 2.994V71.12c0 2.171.899 3.07 2.996 3.07h6.215zm8.762-22.53c-2.246 0-4.119-.6-5.766-1.647v-18.34c1.797-1.646 4.718-2.62 7.339-2.62 4.942 0 7.189 3.444 7.189 10.555 0 8.084-2.846 12.051-8.762 12.051zm40.804 10.18c1.348 0 2.92-.075 4.194-.45 2.171-.524 2.995-1.422 2.995-3.443V54.13c0-1.872-.599-2.62-2.246-2.62-.375 0-.674.075-1.348.075-2.172 0-3.146-1.123-3.146-3.818V9.142c0-2.171-.823-3.07-2.995-3.07h-6.216c-2.097 0-2.995.899-2.995 3.07v39.897c0 9.207 3.295 12.8 11.757 12.8zm31.368.15c13.63 0 20.37-7.112 20.37-21.633 0-14.447-6.74-21.633-20.37-21.633-13.554 0-20.294 7.186-20.294 21.633 0 14.521 6.74 21.632 20.294 21.632zm0-10.33c-5.541 0-7.863-3.294-7.863-11.303 0-8.01 2.322-11.303 7.863-11.303 5.617 0 7.863 3.293 7.863 11.303 0 8.009-2.246 11.302-7.863 11.302zm37.36 9.506c2.17 0 2.995-.898 2.995-3.07V31.075c2.696.374 6.814.823 10.334.823 2.097 0 3.07-.898 3.07-3.069v-6.886c0-2.171-.898-3.07-3.145-3.07-3.594 0-9.136 2.845-11.607 5.914v-2.17c0-2.172-.899-2.995-2.996-2.995h-4.867c-2.097 0-2.996.898-2.996 2.994v35.48c0 2.172.899 3.07 2.996 3.07h6.215zm27.923-41.769c5.017 0 7.788-2.47 7.788-6.811 0-4.267-2.771-6.737-7.788-6.737-4.943 0-7.714 2.47-7.714 6.737 0 4.341 2.771 6.811 7.714 6.811zm3.145 41.769c2.172 0 2.995-.898 2.995-3.07V25.835c0-1.797-1.048-2.62-2.92-2.32-1.198.224-2.097.299-3.22.299-1.049 0-1.947-.075-3.146-.3-1.872-.299-2.92.524-2.92 2.32v32.263c0 2.17.898 3.069 2.995 3.069h6.216zm26.126.823c4.418 0 9.21-1.572 12.356-4.416v.674c0 2.096.899 2.919 2.996 2.919h4.867c2.097 0 2.996-.898 2.996-3.07v-35.48c0-2.096-.899-2.994-2.996-2.994h-6.215c-2.097 0-3.07.898-3.07 2.994v26.349c-1.948 1.647-4.719 2.62-7.04 2.62-4.119 0-5.916-2.32-5.916-8.16V22.616c0-2.096-.824-2.994-2.996-2.994h-6.215c-2.097 0-2.996.898-2.996 2.994v21.783c0 11.901 4.643 17.59 14.229 17.59zm41.702-.823c2.172 0 2.996-.898 2.996-3.07V31.898c2.097-1.796 4.867-2.77 7.189-2.77 4.119 0 5.766 2.47 5.766 8.684v20.285c0 2.17.899 3.069 2.996 3.069h6.215c2.172 0 3.07-.898 3.07-3.07V36.764c0-1.647-.15-3.294-.374-4.791 2.696-1.871 5.317-2.845 7.564-2.845 4.044 0 5.691 2.47 5.691 8.684v20.285c0 2.17.974 3.069 3.07 3.069h6.216c2.172 0 2.996-.898 2.996-3.07V36.314c0-11.826-4.643-17.59-14.304-17.59-5.092 0-9.885 1.721-13.929 5.09-2.321-3.369-5.84-5.09-11.083-5.09-4.643 0-9.36 1.721-12.431 4.416v-.599c0-2.096-.824-2.919-3.07-2.919h-4.793c-2.097 0-2.996.898-2.996 2.994v35.48c0 2.172.899 3.07 2.996 3.07h6.215z"
fill="#333"
fill-rule="nonzero"
/\>
\<path
d="M534.74 22c.444 0 .639-.177.639-.625v-6.93h1.946c.445 0 .64-.19.64-.624v-1.196c0-.448-.195-.625-.64-.625h-6.686c-.444 0-.639.177-.639.625v1.196c0 .434.195.625.64.625h1.945v6.929c0 .448.195.625.64.625h1.515zm5.571 0c.57 0 .834-.177.862-.584.264-3.438.431-4.81.75-6.536h.029c.597 2.134.875 3.234 1.264 5.585.056.42.278.57.82.57h1.224c.542 0 .764-.15.82-.57.389-2.364.667-3.465 1.265-5.598h.027l.034.19.063.376c.248 1.493.407 2.927.654 5.983.028.407.292.584.862.584h1.473c.375 0 .542-.177.542-.53 0-2.269-.959-7.405-1.737-8.927-.209-.407-.431-.543-.946-.543h-1.25c-.529 0-.737.122-.973.543-....

      122 |       render();
      123 |       await loginToEmpl();
    > 124 |       const act = await screen.getByText(/actions/i);
          |                                ^
      125 |       expect(act).toBeInTheDocument();
      126 |     });
      127 |     it("We can hover over information icon", async () => {});
    
      at Object.getElementError (node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:38:19)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:90:38
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:62:17
      at getByText (node_modules/@testing-library/react/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:111:19)
      at _callee16$ (src/tests/pages/Home/Home.test.tsx:124:32)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:294:22)
      at Generator.next (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:119:21)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
      at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
```

this block is pass the test:

```
    it("Renders correctly", async () => {
        mountApp()();
        await loginToEmpl();
        const avatar = screen.getByTestId("dropDownTrigger");
        await userEvent.click(avatar);
        await screen.findByRole("heading", {
          name: mockedData.websocket.initialLoggedInAgents[0].username,
        });
        const profileDropdown = screen.getAllByRole("list")[2];
        expect(
          within(profileDropdown).getByRole("checkbox", { name: "Online" })
        ).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(
          within(profileDropdown).getByRole("button", { name: "Profile" })
        ).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(
          within(profileDropdown).getByRole("button", { name: "Log out" })
        ).toBeInTheDocument();
      });
```

1. I try to use await in `const act = screen.getByText(/actions/i);`
2. I'm sure `screen.getByText(/actions/i);` its there in the DOM

Comment: Show the code under the test, provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example